# Como posso converter os dados da imagem em float? Ou tem algo de errado no codigo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, processamento-de-imagens, matplotlib

Estou testando um codigo e tive problemas: nao consigo ver a imagem. A mensage que aparece é: TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float (dado da imagem nao pode ser convertido para float) Nao consegui resolver isso, por favor me ajude

CODIGO:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('teste8/inco.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('teste8/incoRec.png',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None, flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

Comment: O site é pt-br faça a pergunta em pt-br

Comment: Estou testando um codigo e tive problemas: nao consigo ver a imagem.
A mensage que aparece é: TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float (dado da imagem nao pode ser convertido para float)
Nao consegui resolver isso, por favor me ajude

Google tradutor mandou um abraço! xD